# How to hijack the input stream of tty1 in a ssh session?

Tags: linux, ssh, tty

I have a pi that is connected to my TV via hdmi.  It's setup to automatically login at boot to the console (not x-windows).  In order to control the screen's output on my TV, I must use the keyboard connected to my pi.

I want to be able to login to the pi via ssh and then hijack the tty1 stdin stream, but still allow the stdout to be the hdmi interface.  How can I do this?

I looked at 'screen' but it looks like it takes over both stdin and stdout without the ability to choose just stdin.

```
root@nana ~ # uname -a
Linux nana 3.4.104+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 8 15:40:40 CET 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is open up another shell and have it's output redirected into your tty1 stdout stream.

`script` is an excellent program for capturing output of a program to a file. For example, you could do:

```
script -t0 /dev/tty1 bash
```

The `-t` parameter makes `script` flush its buffer to `/dev/tty1` on every character press, rather than every newline.

Note that this isn't going to be controlling the tty1 shell. Rather, it is simply shoving output from a new shell into it.

If you wanted to have a single, persistent shell shared between tty1 and ssh, you could use `screen`/`tmux`. On your tty1, open up a session (either manually or on login). Then you can simply ssh in and attach to it. Both tty1 and ssh will have control over the exact same session, simultaneously.

Comment: Ty very much!  Script is just what I was looking for.  Only troubles encountered were from trying to run it with sudo.  su'ed to root and it worked perfectly.